Encountering "Error: Exception in ASGI application" for WebSocket server with FastAPI
Hi I am trying to create a simple WebSocket server and client with python and FastAPI.
When I run the server.py and it receives a message from client.py, the server will throw up the follow stack trace and the websocket connection closes, before the loop iterates to open a new websocket server. What is the cause of the error and why does the websocket connection closes?
I sometimes encounter other starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect error messages with code 1006 and 1012 as well.
Appreciate the help, thank you!
Stack Trace shows the console output after running server and client scripts
INFO:     Started server process [17852]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 64479) - "WebSocket /ws" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open
server parsed message
broadcasted message to all connected clients
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\websockets\websockets_impl.py", line 244, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 151, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 373, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 96, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, session)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 94, in app
    await func(session)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 348, in app
    await dependant.call(**values)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\Desktop\Capstone IOT\OCPP\server_A.py", line 80, in websocket_endpoint
    message = await websocket.receive_text()
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 138, in receive_text
    self._raise_on_disconnect(message)
  File "C:\Users\tanka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 130, in _raise_on_disconnect
    raise WebSocketDisconnect(message["code"], message.get("reason"))
starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect: (1000, None)
INFO:     connection closed
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 64483) - "WebSocket /ws" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open

I am appending my python code for reference.
Server.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosedError
import asyncio
import uvicorn

from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep
import starlette

app = FastAPI()

current_file = Path(__file__)
current_file_dir = current_file.parent
project_root = current_file_dir
project_root_absolute = project_root.resolve()
static_root_absolute = project_root_absolute


# serve static files
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=Path(static_root_absolute, 'static')), name="static")


#define message handling
async def server_handle_message(message, ws):
    if(message=="messageA"):
    # handle message A
        await ws.send_text("messageA")
        print("handle message A")

    # handle message B
    elif(message=="messageB"):
        await ws.send_text("messageB")
        print("handle message B")

    else:
        pass


# create a WebSocket endpoint
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    while True:        


            # wait for message from client
        try:
            message = await websocket.receive_text()
            
            await server_handle_message(message,websocket)

            print("server parsed message")
            
            await websocket.send_text(message)
            print("broadcasted message to all connected clients")
    
        except ConnectionClosedError:
            print("Connection Closed Error")
            continue

# start the server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    clients = []
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, ws_ping_interval=600, ws_ping_timeout=60)

client.py
import asyncio
import websockets
import sys

def handle_message(message):
    if(message=="some message A"):
        print("client received msg A")
    
    elif(message=="some message B"):
        print("client received msg B")
    
    else:
        pass

async def receive_messages(ws):

        message = await ws.recv()
        print(f"Received message: {message}")
        handle_message(message)
        print("message was parsed")

async def send_messages(ws):

    message = input("Enter message: ")
        
    if(message=="some text A"):
        print("text A")
        await ws.send("message A")
    
    elif(message=="some text B"):
        print("text B")
        await ws.send("message B")

    else:
       await ws.send(message)

async def main():
    try:
        async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws") as websocket:
            group=asyncio.gather(receive_messages(websocket), send_messages(websocket))
            await group
    except TimeoutError:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:

        try:
            asyncio.run(main())
            print("try to run main() routine")

        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
            print("websocket Exception - Connection closed.  Do cleanup")
            continue
        
        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            print("Asyncio exception - timeout error.  Do cleanup")
            continue

        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("websocket Connection closed.  Do cleanup")
            continue

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interrupted")
            sys.exit(0)     

I have tried reading the FastApi documentation but could not find any solutions.
I have also tried to adjust the websocket ping interval and ping timeout as shown below:
But the problem still persists.
# start the server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    clients = []
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, ws_ping_interval=600, ws_ping_timeout=60)

